# How to set system property of current directory

Tags: java, log4j, jboss6.x

I am working with jboss , i am struggling to set current directory path in properties-service.xml and i want to call that in log4j jdbc adapter for URL

Comment: The current directory in relation to what? What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: My goal is getting my current directory , i mean server directory in log4j jdbc adapter , where as i am logging everything <param name="URL" value="jdbc:sqlite:D:/db/sfLog.db" />, here i have given the sqlite database location static but i how can i give dynamic

Comment: Refer to Jobss community page on [PropertiesService](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/PropertiesService?_sscc=t)

Answer (score 0):

set this in properties-service.xml

CURRDIR=/home/mallika

and then call

System.out.println(System.getProperty("CURRDIR"));

Comment: Thank you satya but , when i suppose develop in another server again i have to set the current by editing  properties-service.xml, and how i can call in log4j xml .

Comment: you can always use System.setProperty("CURRDIR")  = <some-value>; also you can place log4j.xml in conf dir